# Filemaker Field not Found

Tags: php, filemaker

We ( have ) to use filemaker for a customer but we get a field not found error when adding the request.

This is the code we're using which is serving the $_POST values.
(I know that I'm using mass assignment but this is currently in a testing phase)

```
$newRequest = $fm->newAddCommand('REGISTRATIE', $_POST);
$return = $newRequest->execute();
```

When we print the results of `$return` we get the following error without further information.

[image]
Any idea what might be wrong?

### Full Error log

http://pastebin.com/eqYHdDdT

Comment: What's the name of the field?

Comment: Please post the error log instead of an image.

Comment: We have no idea.. This is the only error we're getting back ,it's a big form.. over 25 fields

Comment: http://pastebin.com/eqYHdDdT this is the full error log

Comment: @Notflip If you make a loop and prefix the field names with your table name and a double colon, would that work? E.g.: `tabel::naam`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Web Publishing in FileMaker this way is dependent on layouts. In your example, the layout you are referencing is named "REGISTRATIE" so all the fields must exist on that layout and be accessible.

If that layout is complicated, consider creating a dedicated web accessible layout with only the fields you need to access and/or return.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to what has already been said, general best practice with the Filemaker PHP API is to have a completely separate set of Layouts for API interaction.